# Is there a way to show memory usage to a player in GameMaker?

Tags: memory, game-maker

I mean - you can use "fps" to get current FPS of your game and I am showing it in console. Is there a way I can show there even the memory usage? Or not?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://gmc.yoyogames.com/index.php?showtopic=438215

just found a solution - CleanMem dll !!